# find IP and PORT in use by Apache

Tags: centos, networking, apache-httpd, webserver

How can I find which IP:PORT Apache web server is monitoring? There are some network commands, but they show the TCP port in use. The machine has multiple network interfaces and the `Listen` section in `httpd.conf` is commented. So, one of the is used by default and I don't know which one is set as default.

For example, the following command only shows the port number

```
root@cluster:~# netstat -pat | grep httpd
tcp        0      0 *:ulistproc     *:*      LISTEN      3940/httpd
tcp        0      0 *:https         *:*      LISTEN      3940/httpd
```

Also, I expect that the correct port number should be 80 and not 3940!

Any idea to find that?

Comment: Just as a clarification, that command /does/ show the IP that apache is listening on -- It's listening on `*`, which means *any and all IP traffic that reaches the computer*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As root, type

```
netstat -pat | grep httpd
```

(or `grep apache` depending on your distro)

Comment: That command doesn't show the IP address. it is only saying that port #3940 is in used.

Comment: It does, you were looking in the wrong column.

Answer (score 4):

That last column is the process (process # / process name) and not the port.  The port is in the fourth column, in your case it shows two ports open ulistproc and https.  Both ports are open on the address "*" which means all addresses on your machine (that's normal default for most daemons, there's a config to limit it).  If you want the actual port numbers use "netstat -pant" to keep it from doing the symbolic conversion .

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap localhost

cat httpd.conf | grep port
```

Answer (score 0):

Being root you can run

```
netstat -ntlp | grep httpd

[root@cluster ~]# netstat -ntlp|grep httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      13876/httpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      13876/httpd
```

- :::80 and :::443 are the listening port.
- 13876 is the process id.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using netstat, you can also use `lsof` to list open files (streams, sockets, block files etc.).

```
root@host: lsof -i -n -P |grep httpd
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF   NODE  NAME
httpd    4291 root   3u   IPv4 124715  0t0        TCP   *:80 (LISTEN)
```

> lsof (8)             - list open files
>
> -i = show IPv4/6 files
>   -n = do not resolve hostnames (i.e. show IPs)
>   -P show port numbers instead of friendly names (i.e 80 instead of HTTP).